# Tooltip oddness with whitespace in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I've produced [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q32pzfku/) and it doesn't reproduce the problem, aside from being cut and paste. The only changes are that I've put placeholder data in.

Regardless, the actual issue is that when I have a tooltip with whitespace in, all I get is a small white box on hovering over a column. When it doesn't, I don't. It certainly doesn't work like it does in the fiddle.

Testing on Chromium and Firefox.

Below is the fiddle:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
    'text': 'Risk Factors',
    },
    xAxis: [{
            categories: ['cows', 'pigs', 'onions'],
        }],
        tooltip: {
    },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Risk Score"
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 10
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
            series: [{
                name: 'Risk Scores',
                type: 'column',
                data: [2,3,4],
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="font-weight: bold;">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}</b> ',
                }
    }
            ]
    }
    )
}
)
```

Comment: What version of highcharts are you using on your system? The jsFiddle is pulling the latest version from highcharts (which as of this note is 4.1.8).

Comment: set useHTML: true, in tooltip

Comment: This didn't work. @NishithChaturvedi

Comment: We're using 4.1.4. A similar chart was fine in the same page.